# Alternative to horizontal rule tag `<hr>` working in html5

Tags: css, html, attributes

I am currently working on some html for a calendar (in html5), and I am trying to add in a coloured horizontal line. I have been using the horizontal rule tag `<hr>` but I'm struggling to get most of the attributes to work at all.

This is what I want:

```
<hr color="purple" align="left" width="120%" size="6">
```

I read that some attributes don't work in html5... and the only one that is working is the width tag. None of the others are doing anything!

How can I get this to work? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Use CSS. Not HTML attributes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use CSS rules

```css
hr.someClass {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 120%;
  height: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<hr class="someClass">
```

Comment: Simple question, but I need to get rid of the gaps on the left and right... as in zero margin on each side. any ideas?

Comment: @RuthYoung the space is caused (in the example snippet here) by padding on the body - adding `body { padding-left: 0; }` to your css fixes the example here, and may fix it for you

Answer (score 12):

You could add a div with a `border-top`, as below:

```html
<div style="border-top: 6px solid purple"></div>
```

With external styles (which is always better):

```css
.horizontal-rule {
  border-top: 6px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-rule"></div>
```

Comment: Why can OP not use a `<hr>`? How/why is a `<div>` more suitable?

Comment: @Turnip is OP's question not *literally* asking alternative to horizontal rule tag?

Comment: OP wanted a 6px purple rule, why not just show the complete CSS for that?

Comment: No. It is _"why aren't the attributes applied"_

Comment: @Turnip Well the question states that the OP is having trouble with <hr>, so I've presented an alternative

Comment: @Turnip *Is there a better way to approach this?*

Comment: How is this better?

Comment: @Turnip because a div can be maniplulated in almost any way with CSS - something an hr can't

Answer (score 4):

In HTML 4.01, the `<hr>` tag represents a horizontal rule. In HTML5, the `<hr>` tag defines a thematic break. Also attributes like `align`, `size` and `width` are not supported in HTML5.

The proper alternative to this is defining a div as:

**HTML**

```
<div class="hr"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hr {
    border-top: 6px solid purple;
    width: 120%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<div style="background-color: purple; text-align: left; width: 120%; height: 6px;"></div>
```

here you can give the "background-color" for the "hr" line and height as the border height.
I hope this will work :)